# creating a scheduled task to create an incremental backup of our system files every day

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks

This is a question that i want to solve. This is a linux topic.

creating a scheduled task to create an incremental backup of our system files every day.

1. Use the tar command
2. Use the cpio command
3. Use the dump command

Note: Files that have been changed to the day before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a scheduled task using cron; to edit cron jobs, use `crontab -e` (and maybe choose an editor, nano is very easy for beginners)

Add the following line to it:
`0 1 * * * /path/to/backup/script`
Meaning "at minute 0, hour 1, every day, every month, every day of week execute /path/to/backup/script.sh"

Explaining and posting a backup script is way to much for explaining here, but you can use any you find on google, e.g.: https://gist.github.com/arunk-s/10571807
That specific script will backup to a remove host via ssh, to store in a file simply replace line 38 with
`tar --listed-incremental=$snap-1 -cvpz $sdir > "$ddir/$bfile"`
and line 43 with
`tar --listed-incremental=$snap -cvpz $sdir > "$ddir/full.$bfile"`

Further information on how tar incremental backups work: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_39.html
Further information on crontab: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html

For backups I also recommend using LVM snapshots
- Create LVM snapshot and mount it
- Create backup of LVM snapshot
- Remove LVM snapshot
This way if some files are changed while backup is in process you will still get a persistent backup

Comment: Thanks @tionsys for your answer